# See the center of a long image in browser without scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image with 1920X140px size. The width is so big that in browser I always see the images left part only and the browser shows horizontal scroll bar. How to make browser to show the center of the image and without scroll bar. (The rest part let stay for showing while it is zoomed out)

Comment: this can be easily done by simple css, i already did it but unfortunately i dont remember how it was implemented. it is something like doing a block with fullsize and doing its background CENTER CENTER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign it as a background image of an element (including the `<body>` tag) and give it a background-position of center:

css:

```
background-image: url(path/to/image.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't gave height to my dive, so the background image was not visible. I gave the height and it worked. I have interestingly noticed that when I gave width also, I turn back to the most-left view of my image. The dive lost the centered background property.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS background on a DIV and set the `background-position:` property for your offset.